# How to capture entire webview for the printing

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5

I am new to Qt.  I just wanted to know if it is possible to send the entire `qwebview` into the printer. I am not asking the source code, but

1) is it possible?

2) Do we have any link for the reference?

Answer (score 0):

1) yes it's possible

2) as stated in QWebView documentation

```
A QWebView can be printed onto a QPrinter using the print() function. 
This function is marked as a slot and can be conveniently connected to 
QPrintPreviewDialog's paintRequested() signal.
```

Comment: Thanks evilruff, Do you have any reference URL,where i can see some sample code ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235748/print-text-of-a-qwebview-qprintdialog-doesnt-appear

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes Possible

2) http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/25880-QWebView-prints-PDF-file-OK-with-QPrintDialog-only

Also you can ge HTML from webview and adopt some other printing technique.